# The usepackage notoccite does not work

Tags: citing

I have used `notoccite` to avoid getting citations in my caption to be numbered first but to follow the rest of the document. Unfortunately this does not work. Does any one know what I can do to overcome this problem or does any one know which package to use instead of `notoccite` ( I have tried `\protect\cite`)? I do not know if some of my code interferes with the `\usepackage{notoccite}`. My code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, twoside]{report}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in, headsep=50pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{notoccite}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{1\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        %\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \Huge\bfseries \thechapter\space%
        %\par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 20\p@
  }}
  \def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{1\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 20\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[textfont={rm, it}, labelfont={bf}]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{url} 
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newcommand{\degree}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
\newcommand{\celcius}{\degree{}C}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\newcommand{\aar}{\textit{år}}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\renewcommand\bibname{References}


\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\pagestyle{fancy}     
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[R]{
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{logoside.png}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter. {##1}}}{}}
}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\arabic{section}.\ #1}}


\fancyhead[L]{\fontsize{20}{40} \nouppercase{\leftmark}
  \renewcommand{\plainheadrulewidth}{0.4pt}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{foo,
 author = {Foo},
 title = {Title of Foo},
}
@misc{bar,
 author = {Bar},
 title = {Title of Bar},
}
@misc{ba,
 author = {Ba},
 title = {Title of Ba},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
this is the text \cite{foo} and it should be cited first \cite{bar}
\begin{figure} [h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.65]{A figure}
    \caption[the caption in the list of figure]{the caption in the text\cite{ba}}
    \label{X}
\end{figure} 

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Since there is no list of figures, the package `notoccite` does nothing. It's not really clear what the problem is. By the way, you're loading `hyperref` too early: it should be the last loaded package, in your case.

Comment: Thanks. In my original code, there is a list of figures. The problem is that the references in the figures will be numbered first. In fact, will they be numbered first even if I delete the list of figures. :/

Comment: If I add `\listoffigures`, I get the order “Foo”, “Bar” and “Ba” in the bibliography.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that `notoccite` is incompatible with `hyperref` which undoes the work of the other package.

You can redo it on top of `hyperref`.

Please, revise the settings related to `fancyhdr`: redefining `\chaptermark` in the header is surely wrong.

I reordered your preamble in a more sensible way. Note that `hyperref` must be last (only a few packages should be loaded after it, none among the ones you use).

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{foo,
 author = {Foo},
 title = {Title of Foo},
}
@misc{bar,
 author = {Bar},
 title = {Title of Bar},
}
@misc{ba,
 author = {Ba},
 title = {Title of Ba},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in, headsep=50pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[textfont={rm, it}, labelfont={bf}]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
% do the same as notoccite on top of the redefinitions by hyperref
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \patchcmd{\@starttoc}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\@fileswfalse}{}{}%
  \patchcmd{\@starttoc}{\if@filesw}{\endgroup\begingroup\if@filesw}{}{}%
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{1\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        %\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \Huge\bfseries \thechapter\space%
        %\par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 20\p@
  }}
  \def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{1\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 20\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newcommand{\degree}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
\newcommand{\celcius}{\degree{}C}
%\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents} % already default
\newcommand{\aar}{\textit{år}}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\renewcommand\bibname{References}

\pagestyle{fancy}     
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields

% the following is very wrong
%\fancyhead[R]{
%\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{logoside.png}
%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter. {##1}}}{}}
%}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\arabic{section}.\ #1}}

% the following is very wrong
%\fancyhead[L]{\fontsize{20}{40} \nouppercase{\leftmark}
%  \renewcommand{\plainheadrulewidth}{0.4pt}}

\linespread{1.15}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

this is the text \cite{foo} and it should be cited first \cite{bar}
\begin{figure} [h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}
    \caption{the caption in the text \cite{ba}}
    \label{X}
\end{figure} 

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]